# CSS not loading on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile

So my website looks fine on all devices (even my friends mobiles) but the CSS will not load on my iPhone. I can view the contents of the CSS file but its not being applied. Any help?

Site : (http://www.jacksewell.uk/)

My host said they can't do anything.

head content:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Jack Sewell - Home</title>

    <meta name="description" content="Jack Sewell - Freelance  web developer & designer">
    <meta name="author" content="Jack Sewell">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="assets/favicon-144.png">
    <meta name="application-name" content="Name">
    <meta name="msapplication-tooltip" content="Tooltip">
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="assets/xml/ieconfig.xml">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/favicon-152.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/menu.js"></script>

    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this and haven't had problems, yet
[Device Specific CSS Media Queries Collection](https://gist.github.com/needim/d15fdc2ac133d8078f7c)

I just noticed the different faviconsand tiles in your code. Look at [Favicon Generator](https://realfavicongenerator.net/)
It generates all the different icons and tiles for all current devices and gives you the code to use.

Comment: My host said it a cache issue on my side but I've completely reinstall Chrome etc and the issue is still present. Any help? @mlegg

Comment: You reinstalled but I wonder of there were leftover remnants of Chrome. Did you do this? http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-clear-chrome-browser-history-cache-on-iphone/

Comment: I did that too. It's working now. I just uploaded a new favicon and it started working. Thanks :D

Comment: now lets go one step further and use https://realfavicongenerator.net/  It creates all the favicon images for all major platforms: iOS, Android, Mac OS X Safari. You upload a 260 px X 260 px image and it creates all the different sizes for you and then give you the code to put in your '<head>' section.